# Refreshing of several controls in loop Winforms

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make weather application. And when I input new city in my combobox,my labels and pictureboxes don't refresh. I have  already tried `Refresh()` `Update()` and `Invalidate()` and none of them worked. Tell me please ,what I'm suppose to do. Thank you in advance!

```
 private async void SetWeatherForecastDataToWeatherApp(string city)
    {
        try
        {
            var jsonData = string.Empty;
            var url = string.Format("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q={0}&APPID=a54961a05f7a1fc0cf9bd2bf1465dea5", city);
            var uri = new Uri(url);
            var request = WebRequest.Create(uri);
            var response = await request.GetResponseAsync();

            using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    jsonData = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
                }
            }
            response.Close();

            _jsonFutureWeatherForecastData = jsonData;

            _weatherForecast = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WeatherForecast>(_jsonFutureWeatherForecastData);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Input Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        }


        var dayNameLabelList = new List<Label>();
        var weatherDescriptionLablList = new List<Label>();
        var gradesLabel = new List<Label>();

        var pictureBoxList = new List<PictureBox>();

        int yLocation = 50;
        int xLocation = Width / 2;
        int cnt = 0;


        string currDayOfWeek = string.Empty;
        string CurrentDate = string.Empty;

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {

            currDayOfWeek = _dateConverter.ConvertMilisecondsToCurrentTime(_weatherForecast.WeatherList[i].CurrentDate).DayOfWeek.ToString();
            CurrentDate = _dateConverter.ConvertMilisecondsToCurrentTime(_weatherForecast.WeatherList[i].CurrentDate).Day.ToString();

            cnt++;
            pictureBoxList.Add(new PictureBox());
            pictureBoxList[i].Name = "WeatherForecastImage" + cnt.ToString();
            pictureBoxList[i].Location = new Point(xLocation, yLocation);
            pictureBoxList[i].Load($"Icons/{_weatherForecast.WeatherList[i].Weather[0].Icon}.png");
            Controls.Add(pictureBoxList[i]);
            pictureBoxList[i].Invalidate();

            dayNameLabelList.Add(new Label());
            dayNameLabelList[i].Text = currDayOfWeek + " " + CurrentDate;
            dayNameLabelList[i].Location = new Point(xLocation + 100, yLocation);
            dayNameLabelList[i].Size = new Size(100, 15);
            dayNameLabelList[i].Font = new Font("Lucida Sans", 10, FontStyle.Regular);
            Controls.Add(dayNameLabelList[i]);

            weatherDescriptionLablList.Add(new Label());
            weatherDescriptionLablList[i].Text = _weatherForecast.WeatherList[i].Weather[0].Description;
            weatherDescriptionLablList[i].Location = new Point(xLocation + 100, yLocation + 15);
            weatherDescriptionLablList[i].Font = new Font("Lucida Sans", 8, FontStyle.Regular);
            Controls.Add(weatherDescriptionLablList[i]);

            gradesLabel.Add(new Label());
            gradesLabel[i].Text = _weatherForecast.WeatherList[i].Main.Temperature.ToString("0") + " C°";
            gradesLabel[i].Location = new Point(xLocation + 200, yLocation);
            gradesLabel[i].Font = new Font("Lucida Sans", 10, FontStyle.Regular);
            Controls.Add(gradesLabel[i]);

            yLocation += 100;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < dayNameLabelList.Count; i++)
        {
            dayNameLabelList[i].ForeColor = Color.White;
            weatherDescriptionLablList[i].ForeColor = Color.White;
            gradesLabel[i].ForeColor = Color.White;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would suggest you create a UserControl instead of all those individual controls.  I'd also suggest you finally read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: When are you expecting them to update? As they are added in the loop or after the method finishes?

Comment: @Enigmativy I tried updating methods in the loop and after method finishing ,and it didn't work.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add event handlers to the combo for either SelectedIndexChangedEvent (if it's a non-editable combo), or TextUpdateEvent if it is (likely both in that latter case). Those event handlers then change the other controls as needed.